# is it necessary to replace nan values with mean or mode or median or any other value?

Tags: data-analysis, data-science

I have a dataset conaining about 18 million records. Is it necessary to replace nan values with mean or mode or median or any other value? Is it a good practise to keep nan values as it is and simply ignore nan values during data analysis?

Comment: This is not a programming, but a [Stats question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) and should be asked there. Imho missing values should be treated as such and not be substituted, faking a data set that does not exist. But some functions don't work with missing values, so there you go.

Comment: can you elaborate more?

Comment: It really depends on the requirements. What does the `nan` values mean in your dataset? Does it mean for such rows, that particular features does not exists? If so, ignoring those rows in your analysis seems like a good bet. Does it mean this is an error in data collection? If so, treat it with replacing it by mean/mode/median. As @Mr.T says, stats questions  should be directed to [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). This might not be a correct platform for such questions.

Comment: Thanks. I have posted the question on https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/340138/is-it-necessary-to-replace-nan-values-with-mean-or-mode-or-median-or-any-other-v